# Foursquare API methods upvote / downvote a tip

Tags: foursquare

Since Foursquare encourage developers to post API issues on StackOverflow I wanted to ask: Is there a method for upvote or downvote a tip in Foursqaure API? I have checked the Foursqaure API docs but there aren't any new methods added for tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `v2/tips/like` API to like or unlike a tip.

> If 1, like this tip. If 0 unlike (un-do a previous like) it. Default
>   value is 1.

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/tips/like

UPDATE:

It looks like Foursquare.com uses an undocumented endpoint `v2/tips/vote`. You can see how this works by inspecting network traffic to Foursquare.com and upvoting or downvoting tips.

Upvote: https://api.foursquare.com/v2/tips/TIP_ID/vote?vote=1

Downvote: https://api.foursquare.com/v2/tips/TIP_ID/vote?vote=0

Remove vote: https://api.foursquare.com/v2/tips/TIP_ID/removevote

These all need to be `POST` requests and you'll of course need an oauth token for all of them.

Comment: But like / unlike is different feature from upvote / downvote.